# acronym \acresetall & cleveref: multiply defined labels

Tags: acronyms, cleveref

I'm using the `acronym` package to expand acronyms and I'm also using the `cleveref` package. I would like to have acronyms expanded once per chapter.  For instance in the following code, both acronyms should produce the expansion:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\acrodef{ac}{Acronym}

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}

\ac{ac} 

\acresetall
\chapter{two}

\ac{ac}
\end{document}
```

According to the `acronym` manual I found that calling `\acresetall` before each chapter produces the desired result but I get warning about duplicate labels (somehow a conflict with `cleveref`).  Is there another way to get the desired result or avoid the warning?

Comment: Make a complete example that can be used for testing.

Comment: I edited the post with a MWE.

Comment: I don't get warnings about duplicate labels if I add `\acresetall` before or after `\chapter{two}`

Comment: Right, it seems to be some strange interaction with the `cleveref` package.  I still found no other answer so I updated the question title and text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@verridelabel[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\undonewlabel{#1}}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\undonewlabel{#1@cref}}%Added for cleverref
  \label{#1}%
  \@overriddenmessage rs{#1}%
  \@esphack
}%
\makeatother
\acrodef{ac}{Acronym}

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}

\ac{ac}

\acresetall
\chapter{two}

\ac{ac}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Package `cleveref` extends `\label{<name>}` to add `\label{<name>@cref}`. And package `acronym` sets a label `\label{acro:ac}` twice, in the first and second chapter. However it undoes the first label before setting the second, from the `.aux` file:

```
\AC@undonewlabel{acro:ac}
\newlabel{acro:ac}{{1}{1}}
```

Versions of `acronym` before 2015/03/21 v1.41 are using `\undonewlabel` instead of `\AC@undonuewlabel` (see gtownescapee's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269518/16967)).

The patch below makes the same for the added label by `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\org@overidelabel}{}
\let\org@overridelabel\@verridelabel
\@ifpackagelater{acronym}{2015/03/21}{% v1.41
  \renewcommand*{\@verridelabel}[1]{%
    \@bsphack
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\AC@undonewlabel{#1@cref}}%
    \org@overridelabel{#1}%
    \@esphack
  }%
}{% older versions
  \renewcommand*{\@verridelabel}[1]{%
    \@bsphack
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\undonewlabel{#1@cref}}%
    \org@overridelabel{#1}%
    \@esphack
  }%
}
\makeatother

\acrodef{ac}{Acronym}

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}

\ac{ac} 

\acresetall
\chapter{two}

\ac{ac}
\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file:

```
relax 
\reset@newl@bel
\newacro{ac}[ac]{Acronym}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}one}{1}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\AC@undonewlabel{acro:ac@cref}
\AC@undonewlabel{acro:ac}
\newlabel{acro:ac}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{acro:ac@cref}{{[chapter][1][]1}{1}}
\acronymused{ac}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}two}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\AC@undonewlabel{acro:ac@cref}
\AC@undonewlabel{acro:ac}
\newlabel{acro:ac}{{2}{2}}
\newlabel{acro:ac@cref}{{[chapter][2][]2}{2}}
\acronymused{ac}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both the accepted answer and @Heiko's answer solved this problem for me, until the acronym package was updated to version 1.41 on 2015-03-21.  In this version the implementation changed such that the `\undonewlabel` command was replaced with the `\AC@undonewlabel` command.  To be compatible with v1.41, I recommend @Heiko's answer but replace instances of `\undonewlabel` with `\AC@undonewlabel`.

I would have replied as a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet.